# Recieving values from arduino board , facing problems

Tags: android, arduino, handler, android-bluetooth

I am able to receive values from arduino  but there is a small problem in receiving the thing is that the values coming from arduino in the form of 122|126 and I am setting it to a text view in handler the problem is that when I am debugging it's showing the actual value(**correct format (122|133)**) but when I am running it's showing **some other formats like,
122|,  2|133,  23|122**

I tried a lot to fix this problem , please help me to fix this.
this is my source code,

```
BluetoothDevice myBlueDevice;
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdpter;
TextView contentWrite;
OutputStream mmOutputStream;
InputStream mmInputStream;
String contentMsg;
Activity act;
boolean status;
String read;
Thread workerThread;
byte[] readBuffer;
int readBufferPosition;
int counter;
volatile boolean stopWorker;
Handler bluetoothIn;
BluetoothSocket tmp;

final int handlerState = 0; // used to identify handler message
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();

private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_after_connection);

    contentWrite = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
    contentWrite.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    Intent getAddr = getIntent();
    String blueAddress = getAddr.getStringExtra("Blueaddr");

    bluetoothAdpter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    myBlueDevice = bluetoothAdpter.getRemoteDevice(blueAddress);

    final UUID SERIAL_UUID = UUID
            .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); // UUID for
                                                                    // serial
                                                                    // connection

    tmp = null;

    // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
    // given BluetoothDevice
    try {
        Method m = myBlueDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
                new Class[] { int.class });
        tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(myBlueDevice, 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    bluetoothAdpter.cancelDiscovery();

    try {
        // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
        // successful connection or an exception
        tmp.connect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            tmp.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
        }
        return;
    }
    if (tmp.isConnected()) {

        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(tmp);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        // I send a character when resuming.beginning transmission to check
        // device is connected
        // If it is not an exception will be thrown in the write method and
        // finish() will be called
        mConnectedThread.write("x");

        bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

                // String readMessage = (String) msg.obj; // msg.arg1 =
                // bytes

                contentWrite.setText(contentMsg);

            }
        };

    }
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    // creation of the connect thread
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            // Create I/O streams for connection
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
        int bytes;

        // Keep looping to listen for received messages
        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer); // read bytes from input
                                                    // buffer

                read = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);

                contentMsg = read; // this is the value I am displaying in textview.
                bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, read)
                        .sendToTarget();

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler

            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    // write method
    public void write(String input) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes(); // converts entered String into
                                                // bytes
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer); // write bytes over BT connection
                                            // via outstream
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // if you cannot write, close the application
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Connection Failure" + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // finish();

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStop()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDestroy()",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a formatting problem, you could filter the message as desired inside handleMessage(android.os.Message msg).

It seems that bluetooth is passing an array, so giving it to the setText method produces a comma separated list at runtime

Comment: but actually I  need a general approach like may be later arduino can can send so many values like 123|122|234|345|567, so if I format the string based on that It will create problem..

Comment: each time arduino sends you values, you should then do a String.split("|") on them, so you can separate them and process separately, if that's what you're trying to do

Comment: actually my problem is like, the **read** variable inside run method which will store the value from arduino  is not holding the full value(122|133) thats why I am facing this problem so even if I do split also the same problem will occur